# Pass Argument From tpl Sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

My json is as follow:

```
({
"status":"TRUE",
"message":"Words",
"data":[
{
  "name":"paint",
  "author":"snooky",
  "word_id":"1",
  "category":"Business",
  "definitions":[
    {
      "rating":"Green",
      "defintion":"to put color to in something",
      "def_id":"1",
      "example":null,
      "author":"pit",
      "is_favourite":"yesStar"
    },
    {
      "rating":"Red",
      "defintion":"this is a new definition of word paint.",
      "def_id":"42",
      "example":null,
      "author":"bull",
      "is_favourite":"noStar"
    }
  ]
}
]
})
```

I am parsing this value and show it in tpl as shown below:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    store: 'words',
    height: 140,
    layout: 'fit',
    scrollable: {  
      direction: 'vertical',
      directionLock: true,
    },
    margin: '0 0 5px 0',
    itemTpl: [          
    '<div>',
    '<tpl for="data">',
    '<ul class="parabox">',
    '<li><h2><b>{name}</b></h2>',
    '<tpl for="definitions">',
    '<ul class="para-box-wrapper">',
    '<li class="{rating}"><div >',
    '<div class="paragraph-def" ><p id = "wordDefinition" >{defintion}</p></div>',
    '<span class="authorBox"><i>Author: {author}</i></span>',
    '<div id="favourite" class="{is_favourite}" ></div>',
    '</div>',
    '</li>',
    '</ul>',
    '</tpl>',
    '</li>',
    '</ul>',
    '</tpl>',
    '</div>',
    ].join(''),
    listeners: {
      itemtap : function(list, index, target, record, event) {
  if (event.target.id=='wordDefinition') {
  alert("Rating clicked!");
   console.log(event.target.id);
  console.dir("Definition--"+record);
    //ratingStar();
  }
  if (event.target.id=='favourite') {
   alert('Favourite clicked!');
   console.log(event.target.id);
   console.dir("Favourite--"+record);
  //addToFavourite();
  }
}
}
}
```

My Console is as follow:

![console][1]

As shown in above pic i want to access def_id and word_id when user clicks on the respective tpl as shown in below image when user clicks on definition **i.e overweight football supporter** i need it's word_id and when user clicks on star i need to get word_id.
Doing record.data.data[0].definitions[0].def_id i can get it but i want it to be dynamic as there may be 4-5 definition later.

![rate][2]

My store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.wordsmenu',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store', 
config:
{
autoLoad:true,
model: 'MyApp.model.words',    
id:'Contacts',
proxy:
{
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'json', 
    reader:
    {
            rootProperty:''
    }
}
}
});
```

My model are:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.words', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
   fields: [
        {name: 'status', mapping: 'status'},
        {name: 'message', mapping: 'message'},
        {name:'data', mapping: 'data'},
        {name: 'definitions', mapping: 'definitions.defintion'},
        {name: 'ratings', mapping: 'definitions.rating'},
    ]
}
});
```

I am able show json value in tpl. Now, i should keep track of click on specific 
definition and star and send its id to server but unable to get id.

For reference of record you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397623/how-to-get-value-form-record-in-sencha-touch/18403719#comment27098809_18403719).
Any Help!

Comment: What is the current result of what you are doing?  What is the console printing out?

Comment: output when i do console.dir(record) can be seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397623/how-to-get-value-form-record-in-sencha-touch/18403719#comment27098809_18403719.we both were working on same project but now i am working on it solely.

Comment: The record in that screenshot does not look like the models that you have listed above.  What is the field name of the "id" that you are trying to obtain in the `itemtap` listener?  If your model is setup correctly, it should be as simple as `record.get('id_field')`

Comment: @kevhender, can you please guide me, how to create efficient and working model for my json i am stuck onto this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not following what exactly you are trying to do, or what it is that you are currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `roll_id` is a field of your model, so you should be able to get it from your record:

```
var rollId = record.get('roll_id');
ratingStart(rollId);
```